# Boolean - subtract multiple objects from one with only one boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine

Is there a way to subtract multiple objects from one using single boolean modifier? For example I have a wall, and I need to make multiple holes in it for windows. I wanted to parent an object that will make a hole in the wall to a window object, so wherever I move the window, the hole will be made automatically, and if I duplicate the window, the object that is it's child will be duplicated too, and will generate holes too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The boolean modifier only works with one object, but that object could have multiple separate meshes. So you can either join all your windows into one object, or add additional boolean modifiers to achieve this.

Comment: but best results if you do it one by one, boolean is prone to errors

Answer (score 7):

Subtracting multiple objects from another object with just a single "boolean" modifier is possible in Blender 2.91:

1. Create a new collection: Right-click inside the object list in the upper right - "New collection"
2. Move all the objects that you want to subtract into this collection
3. Create a new boolean modifier for the original object
4. As "Operand Type" choose "Collection" instead of "Object" from the drop-down menu
5. Pick the collection in the "Collection" field underneath
6. Continue as you usually would

Step 4 and applying the modifier can take quite a while, depending on how many objects there are and how many vertices they have, so I wouldn't recommend doing it this way if complex objects are involved. Instead rather subtract the objects one by one or group only a few of them together.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't input multiple objects into a single boolean modifier.

You can add as many boolean modifiers as you want though. Simply create multiple boolean modifiers with their respective object's input.

You can also join all objects into a single object and use that as the boolean input. E.g. you could duplicate your window, then merge it into the boolean input object by <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> selecting the input object (making it active) and pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join them.

As you intend to speed up the process, I'd advise you to use the built-in BoolTools addon, which creates a shelf for assign boolean quickly.